# Automating SMTP Configuration

Tags: batch, script, automation, iis, smtp

The following is an excerpt from a series of instructions I am following as a list of company procedures they would like me to automate.  Is the following achievable through command line/batch, and if so can someone please point me in the right direction as to how?

Configure SMTP

---

1. Ensure the SMTP service is set to automatic startup:

   `Server Manager -> Tools -> Services -> scroll down to “Simple Mail Transfer Protocol” -> double click`

   - Set Startup type = “Automatic”
   - Click Start
   - Click Ok
2. Configure SMTP

   `Server Manager -> Tools -> Internet Information Services (IIS) 6.0 Manager`

   - Expand the local computer
   - Right click SMTP Virtual server #1
   - Select properties
   - Click Access tab
   - Relay: select “only the list below”
   - Click Add
   - Single Computer
   - 127.0.0.1
   - Click OK
   - Click Messages Tab:
   - Limit message size to (KB): 5120
   - Limit session size to (KB): 51200
   - Limit number of messages per connection to: 20
   - Limit number of recipients per message to: 100
   - Send copy of Non-delivery Report to: support@somedomain.com
   - Badmail directory: c:\inetpub\mailroot\Badmail
   - Click Delivery tab:
   - Advanced -> Fully qualified domain name: smtp.somedomain.net

Step 1 I am pretty sure I have figured out:
`sc config SMTPSVC start= auto`

Step 2 on the other hand I am a bit perplexed on and have been googling furiously in search of a solution.  The closest things I have come across are posts stating I will need to modify metabase information for IIS since the SMTP virtual server is still built in IIS6. (source: http://forums.iis.net/t/1172439.aspx)

Does step 2 simply need to be a manual step or as I asked in the beginning is this setup able to be automated?

Thanks for any and all information.

JD

Comment: that's probably doable with powershell, maybe this will help http://blogs.technet.com/b/bspieth/archive/2013/02/19/configure-the-iis-6-smtp-server-with-wmi-and-powershell.aspx

Comment: @wmz Thank you very much for the reference I will read over this, this afternoon and see what I can learn from it.